# Error while trying to connect Django to Micro soft server - Error was: No module named 'sql_server'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to connect Django to remote Microsoft Server, but I keep getting the following error :

I have installed the followings :
django-mssql 
pyodbc 
django-pyodbc 
django-pyodbc-azure

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named 'sql_server'


DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'OPTIONS':{
        "driver": "FreeTDS",
        "extra_params": "tds_version=7.3",
    },
    'NAME': 'db_name',
    'USER': 'user_name',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'host_address',
    'PORT': '1433'
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried? pip install django-pyodbc ?This link may help https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/#installation

Comment: `sql_server.pyodbc` is from [django-pyodbc-azure](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/). Did you install that? How?

Comment: Yes I have installed the required, but no chance ... I actually can connect to the database using standalone python app ... I can't just connect through Django